# Escaping double quote character

Tags: german

I'm writing an English text while still using a German language package for the occasional umlauts in German names or similar by using the `nGerman` package:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

The way umlauts are written is typing a double quote character followed by the "base letter" of the umlaut:

```
"u
```

becomes:

```
ü
```

Now my problem is that I'm writing something surrounded by double quotes while a word starting with a possible umlaut is followed by it.

```
"welcome" at
```

becomes

```
"welcomeät
```

That's not what I wanted. Therefore how do I escape the `"` to make sure it's not interpreted for umlauts?

Comment: You should never use `"` for denoting quotes. Can you make a minimal compilable example? If you're writing an English text, using `ngerman` will do wrong hyphenation. And ü can always be obtained by `\"u`

Comment: Why not use Unicode input, avoiding macros for umlauts? For the quotation marks, use either TeX quotation-mark macros (two backticks for the open quote and two apostrophes for the close quote), or use the `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing `babel`, in my opinion. Moreover, quotes should never be input with `"`.

If you load `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, the hyphenation of English will be mostly wrong.

```
``Welcome'' at W\"urzburg
```

is the correct input and doesn't require `babel`.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't really need `babel` :-)